# Getting error while deploy ear on Jboss eap 6.4

Tags: deployment, jboss, ear

I am getting problem while deploying ear file on jboss eap 6.4 server.
Below are the logs. Please help.

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."process-engine.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsp.JspInitializationListener".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0", JBAS014799: ... and 7 more ] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."process-engine.ear#org.jbpm.domain" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."process-engine.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0".realm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."process-engine.ear"."cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/cetera-process-engine-api-1.0.0"] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."process-engine.ear".WeldStartService

13:21:39,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found process-engine.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called process-engine.ear.dodeploy

Comment: 1#Analyze the server configuration file, log and configuration files packaged in the application package.  2# Ensure an application dependencies are not undeployed.  3#  check your extension configuration parser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `standalone.xml` of `JBOSS`. Check whether there is any deployment tag in `standalone.xml` and clear it off then run the the project :)

This is because:
If not correct, you might have copy someone `standalone.xml` in your project and `JBOSS` would have added the project it ran within `<deployment>` tag and when it search then there is no `.war`(as it is not ur project) so it prompt the missing dependencies error.

So clear it and run. Let me know if any issue :)